# Warning: Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working on react-router-dom and in console this error is appearing.

> Warning: Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack

Comment: can you please show the code in question? And describe a bit more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: What is your question? If you want to get rid of the message, the error says it all. You are pushing a route that leads to the same place you are currently in.

Comment: Could you please explain why you are navigating to the same path? That's what is usually done by reloading.

Comment: I think your trying to push same url path in <Link to="/same-path">. Try to push different path in <Link to="/diff-path"/> tag.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Use Replace

add '**replace**' to the NavLink or Link

```
<NavLink exact to="/myProfile" replace >My Propile</NavLink>
```

or

```
<Link to="/myProfile" replace />
```

Answer (score 5):

Basically, the problem is that if you are on page `/here` and click a link to `/here`, you end up with essentially duplicate (just different keys) location objects. Please confirm that your pushing the different paths in `<Link to='/diff'/>`

checkout this link for more reference: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5996

Answer (score 0):

I got this message. I change the routing variable to function

before message:

```
    const routing = (
      <Switch>
        ...
      </Switch>
    );
```

fixed to:

```
    const routing = () => (
      <Switch>
        ...
      </Switch>
    );
```