# React Router push to state warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

```
Warning: Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack
```

Hi guys I need to remove this warning on my app using React-router-dom: 5.1.2

I use it in this way

```
<Suspense fallback={some component}>
    <Switch>
    {/* PAGE */}
    <Route render={(routeProps: RouteComponentProps<any>) => <Component {...routeProps}/>}
           path={`${Route.PATH}`}/> </Switch></Suspense>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157214/warning-hash-history-cannot-push-the-same-path-a-new-entry-will-not-be-added-t, checkt this answer maybe help you

Comment: @IlCastro yep, seen but it's not worked for me